# AngularUI ui-select2 causes "select" to be dirty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, directive

I am trying to have angular validation on my page.

I have a plunkr here that shows a normal select that behaves the way you would expect.  It starts off not selected, when you select an option and then go back to the blank option, the error shows up:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SEgsPRaRCjVnpV0PGxJf?p=preview

However, if I change that to a ui-select2, it automatically makes it dirty and shows the error message on load.  Any thoughts on a workaround for this?  thanks in advance!

Comment: can you update the plunker to actually show the problem, including use of ui-select2? Even better, have 2 selects in the plnkr, one that is with, and one without ui-select2?

Comment: @AndrewKuklewicz I've updated my post with the new plnkr!

Comment: There is an issue opened (and closed) for this exact bug (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/6), so you might want to take your chances there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem with angular-ui and select2.
Seems like it has been resolved, but I never got it working.

In my case I just moved to chosen.js.

I found [this post](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-chosen-plugin-awesome/) and after some small changes I ended up with the following directive:

https://gist.github.com/royts/5894780

It is working great and not marking the form as dirty after initialization , and it looks better (you can still see the chosen options but they are great, line wrapping looks better).